# rspec throwing nil error on fabricated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am getting this rspec error in spec/views/posts/index.html.haml_spec.rb :

```
undefined method `in_time_zone' for nil:NilClass
```

this is the line in the view (index.html.haml) getting the error

```
= event.event_datetime.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').strftime('%a, %l:%M %p')
```

I definitely fabricate the event_datetime in my Event fabricator

```
Fabricator(:event) do
  event_datetime { 5.days.from_now }
```

This is the rspec test

```
describe "posts/index.html.haml" do  
  context "with events" do

    before(:each) do     
      view.stub(:sign).and_return("+")         
      assign(:events, [
        an_event1 = stub_model(Event),
        an_event2 = stub_model(Event),
        an_event3 = stub_model(Event)
      ])
    end

    it "displays the page" do
      render
      rendered.should contain("EventName")
    end 
  end
end
```

Any ideas? event.event_datetime should not be nil... I clearly fabricate it.

Comment: please post your index template and action code.

Comment: = event.event_datetime.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').strftime('%a, %l:%M %p')